# Can't open jupyter notebook from anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On my Windows 7 64-bit, I installed Anaconda3 v4.4.0 in `C:\Anaconda3`. Now, after launching Anaconda Navigator, I can't launch jupyter notebook from there. What should I do?

I installed Anaconda3 using an admin account, and then switched to a normal user account to use it. I'm not sure if this could have any effect.

Comment: Have you set the environmental PATH for the normal user?

Comment: @athos *I can't launch jupyter notebook from there* - from where? I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. What **exactly** are you trying to do, and what are the **exact** problems? Do you get any error logs? If so, could you please post them?

Comment: @Zealseeker no i didn't. after adding it, after clicking "jupyter notebook", a tab is opened on chrome for http://localhost:8889/tree?token=af63c4d12733bf5cb5b543316ad6e80582b4aa505195123f , and says "
Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 

Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.

For assistance, contact your network support team."

Comment: @athos I've no idea about the error. You may try to browse 127.0.0.1:8889 or set the ip when starting jupyter. (use `jupyter notebook --help` to get more information)

Comment: @Zealseeker changing to 127.0.0.1... gets error msg: "This site can’t be reached. 10.3.45.100 refused to connect." Where can i type "jupyter notebook --help" command?

Comment: @athos in cmd (http://www.wikihow.com/Open-the-Command-Prompt-in-Windows). I think this is not the problem of jupyter but your network environment, which goes beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @Zealseeker indeed, run from command line got same error with "localhost", i'll check it out, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" in proxy settings.